# ¿Cómo generar PDF que mantenga los estilos de Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap, pdf

¿Cómo puedo generar un pdf con estilos de bootstrap?

Comment: Hola Alan. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Te invito a que conozcas a la comunidad y su funcionamiento visitante [esta presentación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Además te puedo adelantar que este sitio no es para pedir sugerencias u opiniones, sino para pedir respuestas específicas a problemas específicos de programación.

Comment: no puedes generar pdf en el cliente, deberias enviar los datos al servidor  ygenerarlo alli para luego enviar el byte array del archivo al cliente para su descarga. Que sea bootstrap y angular no tiene importancia porque no es con estos que los generas, debes hacerlo en el servidor usando los datos de la pantalla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí puedes generar un `PDF` en el cliente. Dependiendo qué tantas cosas tenga ese `PDF` que desees exportar, te recomiendo revisar la libreria `jsPDF` en el siguiente enlace: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

Comment: Gracias ya e podido generar el pdf, pero pierde el estilo de bootstrap al crearlo, eso a que se debe?